# ArrayAdapter not loading images

Tags: android, image, android-layout, adapter

I have some images to load to my list view with my custom adapter (Contain Image view only ) below is my code

```
    public class menuadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

    int[]images;
    Context context;

    public menuadapter(Context context, int[] imgs) {
        super(context,R.layout.menurow, imgs);

        this.context=context;
        this.images=imgs;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menurow,parent,false);
        ImageView menuimg = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.menuimg);
        menuimg.setImageResource(images[position]);
        return row;
    }
}
```

and for the Main Activity

```
int[] images={R.mipmap.coding,R.mipmap.newsfeed,R.mipmap.comm,R.mipmap.contactus};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView menulist = (ListView ) findViewById(R.id.mainmenu);
    menuadapter menuadapter = new menuadapter(this,images);
    menulist.setAdapter(menuadapter);
}
```

when i run the app its just show nothing :) but if i add a string array to my adapter its worked fine ?? any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Use an image loading library to load the images. Such as Picasso or Glide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like this way, I have checked it works fine.

How to **Set Adapter**:

```
Integer[] images={R.mipmap.coding,R.mipmap.newsfeed,R.mipmap.comm,R.mipmap.contactus};
ListView menulist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainmenu);
menuadapter menuadapter = new menuadapter(this, R.layout.menurow, images);
menulist.setAdapter(menuadapter);
```

**menuadapter.java**

```
public class menuadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

        private Integer[] images;

        public menuadapter(Context context, int resource, Integer[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);

            images = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menurow,parent,false);
            ImageView menuimg = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.menuimg);
            menuimg.setImageResource(images[position]);
            return row;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.